# Parse out specific text from web crawl output

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need this portion of an HTML page parsed out and output to a CSV file, then have it wait for the next output. I'm at a loss when it comes to regex's.

```
<h1>Member Information</h1>


<h2>Company Name</h2>
<p>Address<br />
More Address<br />
City<br />
State<br />
Postal code<br />
</p>
<p><strong>Contact:</strong> Firstname Lastname, PH.D., P.ENG. - <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a><br /></p>
<a href="http://www.domain.com">www.domain.com</a><br />
<p><strong>Phone:</strong> (555)555-5555<br /></p>

</div><!-- end #content -->
```

I can do without the address information but the company name, ID *(which comes from the url)*, First/Last Name *(and title if possible)*, email, URL and phone number would be incredibly valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Never use regex for parsing HTML (or XML, Json, CSV...).

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead, an excellent library already written for such a task.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = BS(htmltext)
soup.h2.text
>>> 'Company Name'
```